# Set of products of open sets is basis for product space

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $(X, \mathcal{T}_X), (Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$ be topological spaces, with bases $\mathcal{B}_X ⊆ \mathcal{T}_X, \mathcal{B}_Y ⊆ \mathcal{T}_Y$, respectively. We define the topology on $X × Y$ to be the topology generated by $S = \{U × Y\mid U ∈ \mathcal{T}_X \} ∪ \{X × V \mid V ∈ \mathcal{T}_Y\}$, in the sense that $S$ is a *subbasis* for $\mathcal{T}_{X × Y}$.

**To demonstrate:** $\mathcal{B}_{X ×Y}:=\{U × V ⊆ X × Y \mid U ∈ \mathcal{B}_X, V ∈ \mathcal{B}_Y\}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{T}_{X × Y}$.

Saying that $S$ is a subbasis for $\mathcal{T}_{X × Y}$ is to say that the open sets of the product space consist precisely of all unions of finite intersections of elements of $S$.

Saying that $\mathcal{B}_{X ×Y}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{T}_{X × Y}$ is to say that the open sets of the product space consist precisely of all unions of elements of $\mathcal{B}_{X ×Y}$.

These two statements are indeed equivalent if the elements of $\mathcal{B}_{X ×Y}$ are precisely the finite intersections of elements of $S$. Indeed, any element of $\mathcal{B}_{X ×Y}$ can be written as $U × Y ∩ X × V$, for $U ∈ \mathcal{B}_X, V ∈ \mathcal{B}_Y$. $\square$

Would you consider this a clean proof? Or a proof at all? It feels as if I haven't *quite* made the ends meet at the end of the proof.

**Edit**

I'm having some more doubts: if we let $\tilde{S} \supseteq S$ be the set of all finite intersections of elements of $S$, then the above shows that $\mathcal{B}_{X ×Y} ⊆ \tilde{S}$. Now, $\tilde{S}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{T}_{X ×Y}$ by definition of $S$ and the product topology, but as $\mathcal{B}_{X ×Y}$ can be smaller, this doesn't seem to prove it...

**Edit 2**

We do have

$$S \supseteq \{U × Y \mid U ∈ \mathcal{B}_X\} ∪ \{X × V \mid V ∈ \mathcal{B}_Y\}.
$$
Now we have to use that fact that $\mathcal{B}_X$ and $\mathcal{B}_Y$ are bases, but I'm not yet seeing how exactly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not in general true that $\mathcal{B}_{X\times Y}=\tilde S$, but it **is** true that

$$\left\{\bigcup\mathscr{U}:\mathscr{U}\subseteq\mathcal{B}_{X\times Y}\right\}=\left\{\bigcup\mathscr{U}:\mathscr{U}\subseteq\tilde S\right\}\,.\tag{1}$$

Since you know that $\mathcal{B}_{X\times Y}\subseteq\tilde S$, you need only prove that

$$\left\{\bigcup\mathscr{U}:\mathscr{U}\subseteq\tilde S\right\}\subseteq\left\{\bigcup\mathscr{U}:\mathscr{U}\subseteq\mathcal{B}_{X\times Y}\right\}$$

in order to prove $(1)$.

- First show that every $W\in\tilde S$ is of the form $U\times V$ for some $U\in\mathcal{T}_X$ and $V\in\mathcal{T}_Y$.
- Then show that every set of the form $U\times V$ for some $U\in\mathcal{T}_X$ and $V\in\mathcal{T}_Y$ is the union of members of $\mathcal{B}_{X\times Y}$.